# How can I make an async messagebox?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, messagebox

I am using `asyncio`, when I tried to run a `ctypes` `messagebox` in parallel with the thing I wanted to run, too, but it didn't work. Also it didn't help when using `pyautogui`. Is there a way? I am desperate.

My current code:

```py
import asyncio
import time
import ctypes

async def do1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your text", "Your title", 1)

async def do2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    for i in range(100): print(".", end="")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    do1(),
    do2()
))
write("exit")

loop.close()
```

First, the `messagebox` appears and only after I click OK on the `messagebox`, the thing I want at the same time (here it's represented by printing of dots) happens. I want the second function to execute when I have not yet pressed OK.

Comment: We cannot possibly help you without seeing the least amount of code necessary to replicate the issue you describe (see [mre]) per [ask]

Comment: You are asking us to imagine what you have written and then tell you where the problem might be. We need a [MCVE].

Comment: @esqew added example